# Does redirecting www to https:// require AllowOverride or can it be set globally?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to change my apache2 server configuration which I'm sure is sub-optimal.  Right now I have all the AllowOverride set to None.  I would like to keep that configuration to set global rules and increase page load times.

However, the problem now is that I use a separate virtual host and directory with a .php file to redirect www.example.com to https://www.example.com.  I'm sure that this is not optimal.  I would prefer to use a mod_overwrite.

From what I have read, a rule set like the following would enable this.  However, I would like to know where to put this code if I want to keep AllowOverride None.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I believe that if I add a rule set like this in the right place, I can also disable the additional virtual host that I'm using to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You should place the rewrite rules in a

```
<Directory /some/where>
[...]
</Directory>
```

block in the apache config. Thus, you do not need any .htaccess file and therefore no change to AllowOverride.

Comment: I ended up adding those exact lines of code to the virtual host that was directing to another directory with a php file that was again directing to the https:// .  That solved the problem.

Comment: You stated that you wanted to drop the virtual host so I opted for the `<Directory>` tag. You should not need any php file (which will not be hit if the request references to anything other than / or /index.php) or additional vhosts (other than the one/s for port 80 and 443). Consult the apache documentation, it is very comprehensive and well-organized.